# Designing a star pattern in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was trying to draw the star patter in react native where instead of stars, there are suppose to be square boxes.

Star pattern would look like this

```
****
****
****
****
****
```

In Vanila JS, it would look like

```
let rows=5;
 for(let i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
  for(let j=1; j<=5; j++){   
   document.write('*');
  }
  document.write('<br />');
}
```

But that's vanila JS and I want to make the same in React-native functional component and then display it in JSX

Consider this my functional component in react native

```
let numberOfBoxesRequired = 4; 
let array = []

const gridBoxes  = (props) => {

    for (let i=0; i<numberOfBoxesRequired; i++) {
        for (let j=0; j<numberOfBoxesRequired; j++) {

        }
    }
    return (
        <View style={mainGridBox}>  

        </View>
    )
}
```

Question: How can I do it?

Comment: isn't `numberOfBoxesRequired` already a number? Why `numberOfBoxesRequired.length` ?

Comment: @VishalSharma FIxed it :) My bad ;\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same in vanilla JavaScript and React:

```
const starLines = Array(4).fill('*'.repeat(4));
```

Once there's data, it can be output in a way that is specific to current application.

In plain JavaScript:

```
document.write(starLines.join('<br />'));
```

In React Native:

```
<View style={mainGridBox}>{starLines.map(line => <Text>{line}</Text>)}</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to render your boxes:

```
let numberOfBoxesRequired = 4; 

const gridBoxes  = (props) => {
    let boxes = [];
    for (let i=0; i<numberOfBoxesRequired; i++) {    
        for (let j=0; j<numberOfBoxesRequired; j++) {
            boxes.push(<Box />); // assume Box is your box component
        }

    }
    return (
        <View style={mainGridBox}>  
            {boxes} // render the boxes
        </View>
    )
}
```

Then you will have to style your gridBox:

```
.mainGridBox {
  flex: 1,
  flexWrap: "wrap";
}

.box {
  flexBasis: 0.25; // this will make a box fill 25% of the container width
  width: 30;  // example width
  height: 30; // example height
}
```

This is the closest to your implementation, but I suggest you use `Array.map()` like **estus** pointed out in his answer.

Comment: @Stundiji, Trying it out but shouldn't `let boxes = [];` be in global scope?

Comment: We declare it in the function scope, because it is only used inside the function.